# Should the coordinating conjunction be preceded by a comma when there is an introductory element that covers both clauses?

Tags: commas, dependent-clause, independent-clauses

If there exists an introductory, dependent clause/phrase that is meant to describe both or all clauses of a sentence, do we add a comma before the coordinating conjunction?

> Tomorrow, Bob will go to the store, and Stacey will stay to prepare dinner.

Or

> Tomorrow, Bob will go to the store and Stacey will stay to prepare dinner.
> .

I know that most examples in this will be bad writing and can be fixed in other ways, but for the sake of curiosity, should one say the comma should be excluded since, in the case of the introductory clauses applying to both clauses, they are not necessarily “independent”?

Comment: Good question, but the comma helps even thought *Tomorrow* applies to both parts.

Comment: In this example, the comma is not needed to do essential 'policing' duties (to distinguish readings). In both variants the scope of 'tomorrow' includes both activities. However, it does aid parsing slightly, and the sentence is getting long enough to merit a signalled pause for breath when read aloud. But both versions are quite acceptable.

Comment: I think 3 of the possible permutations (no commas, 2 commas, or *only the first comma*) are all "credible", except I'm not too keen on 2 commas. But I can't really imagine any context where the fourth permutation (second comma only) would sound (or *read*) "natural".

Comment: I'd say that it's optional.

Comment: There is no comma configuration that automatically makes *tomorrow* apply to one or both clauses. In any case, you  still have independent clauses, but the comma can be omitted under *Chicago Manual of Style*’s advice for coordinating “very short and closely connected” clauses.

Comment: In that example, how could it hurt to drop 'Tomorrow…'? The second example seems to me more natural, but comma usage is one of the most contentious parts of English…